# how to fill the missing value when constructing a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to store a large but very sparse matrix(50,000 rows*100,000 columns), each element of this matrix is a float number from 0.00 to 1.00. The original element values are stored in a python dict (only the elements of known values are stored).

Now the problem is how to construct a pandas.DataFrame from dict effiently.

If I use float64, then a coarse estimation of the physical size of this matrix will be: **(50,000 * 100,000 * 8) = 37GB**, which is significantly larger than the memory size of my machine.

However, I notice that, as the range of each element is from 0.00 to 1.00 and I only care the first 2 digits, I could transform each element into a unsigned 8-bit integer by multiplying with 100 and then cast to np.uint8, which could reduce this dataframe to an acceptable size: **(1/8  * 37GB)**.

I tried this method, but the pandas.DataFrame does not work as I expect. When I specify the dtype in pd.DataFrame() constructor, the final result is still float64.

Here is an example code:

```
In [87]: dc = {'A':{'a':np.uint8(1.2), 'c':np.uint8(3.2)}, 'B':{'a':np.uint8(1.2), \
               'b':np.uint8(2.2)}, 'C':{'b':np.uint8(2.2), 'd':np.uint8(4.2)}}

In [88]: dc
Out[88]: {'A': {'a': 1, 'c': 3}, 'B': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'C': {'b': 2, 'd': 4}}

In [89]: type(dc['A']['a'])
Out[89]: numpy.uint8

In [90]: df = pd.DataFrame(dc, index=['a', 'b', 'c','d'], dtype=np.uint8)

In [91]: df
Out[91]: 
    A   B   C
a   1   1 NaN
b NaN   2   2
c   3 NaN NaN
d NaN NaN   4

In [92]: df.dtypes
Out[92]: 
A    float64
B    float64
C    float64
dtype: object
```

@zero323 mentioned this is a design choice of pandas, so, is there any way to construct this dataframe efficiently?

Comment: The reason this happens is because `NaN` cannot be represented by an integer, once this is present the dtype will be converted to the appropriate type, in this case float. So you have to make a decision whether to drop the `NaN` values, replace them with something like 0 or other value that can be represented by an `int`

Comment: @EdChum Thanks, is there any way that I could construct a pandas.DataFrame and fill the missing value at the same time?

Comment: No, it would have to be done after the construction or you'd have to fill in the missing values yourself, not as straightforwrd with dicts but a numpy array would have various methods for filling the blanks, the other thing to consider is a [sparse dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html)

Comment: @ice_lin I've posted an update. It is not the most efficient way but you can try if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't help you but it is an expected behavior. Citing [Caveats and Gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions)

> When introducing NAs into an existing Series or DataFrame via reindex or some other means, boolean and integer types will be promoted to a different dtype in order to store the NAs.

Comment by @EdChum provides optimal solutions but if really have to work with dicts then you can try something like this:

```
# Choose some default value
default = 0
# Prepare dict with defaults
defaults = {k: default for k in chain(*(x.keys() for x in dc.values()))}

# Fill gaps if needed and construct data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {k: dict(defaults.items() + v.items()) for k, v in dc.items()},
    index=['a', 'b', 'c','d'], dtype=np.uint8)
```